# A Flexible Layout manager that will change the layout according to resize

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

In my `JPanel`, I have 6 buttons laid out in a row (using `FlowLayout` as of now). The default size of the panel is enough to accommodate these buttons in one row. But, when the `frame` is resized it gets stuck at the size that is the sum of the minimum sizes of each button.

I need a layout manager that simply puts the buttons in a new row on re-sizing of the panel.
I'm pretty new to Java Swing so I apologize in advance if this is a trivial question.

Comment: It's not trivial at all, in fact in the standard there's not a layout for every situation, although GridbagLayout is quite flexible. I concurr with @lance-java that MigLayout is by far the most efficient and practical layout.

Comment: @YagoMéndezVidal Thank you, I'm trying the miglayout now

Comment: So, i used a [link](http://www.uffesorensen.dk/Uni/dat1/doc/dat1/path/gui/ModifiedFlowLayout.html) which is the code for a ModifiedFlowlayout() and then added a Thread to revalidate the panels every 100 ms

Answer (score 3):

[MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) is by far the best layout manager I've ever used. Things that used to require nested containers and lots of hard to understand code can be done in a single container with simple to understand (and maintain) string constraints.

Comment: Checking it out, Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The flow layout is capable of your desired behavior (moving components into new row if they cannot fit). Check out the [swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html) (run FlowLayoutDemo). You'll have to show us your source code to find out, whether there is some other constrain which prevents it.

Comment: FlowLayout was not working for me, I'm trying out MigLayout for now

Answer (score 0):

FlowLayout does actually paint components on a new row, but the problem is that the preferred size of the panel doesn't change so in many cases you can't see the components (unless you happen to add the panel to the CENTER of a BorderLayout).

One solution is to use the [Wrap Layout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/), which extends FlowLayout to recalculate the preferred size of the panel so that you see the buttons on a new row.

Comment: The WrapLayout did not seem to work, but thank you for the suggestion

Comment: @ContinuousError, post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.